# How to make a Key-Binding Handle Any Subsequent Keystroke?

Tags: key-bindings

I want to set `C-c j` with such a function (called `cmd`), which can *handle subsequent keystrokes*.

For example, after typing `C-c j` Emacs will execute `cmd`, then every subsequent `j` will invoke `cmd` again.  
Any non-`j` *keystroke* will **interrupt** this process.  It won't invoke `cmd`; instead, it acts **like a simple *keystroke* without the prefix** `C-c`.

Another example is `S-<arrow-key>`:
[11.6 Shift Selection](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shift-Selection.html):

> If you set `shift-select-mode` to the value `permanent`, cursor motion keys that were not shift-translated will not deactivate the mark, so, for example, **the region set by prior commands can be extended by shift-selection, and *unshifted cursor motion keys* will extend the region set by shift-selection.**

Comment: Is the purpose of it to save one intermediate C-x z key sequence which would do the same by repeating z?

Comment: @Claudio: For the 1st example, yes, surely it saves an intermediate `C-x z`; for the 2nd one, in addition to omitting that key sequence, it **distributes subsequent keystrokes to a set of relevant commands**.
Or, the functionality shown in the 2nd example can meet the need in the 1st example.
I think I didn't make it clear enough in the question description, sorry for that ... But, anyway, answers providing either the first or second functionality is useful; they're helpful to the person who browses the related topic.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you try to say about the other example. In my eyes it would make sense to ask for a way you can choose after preliminary C-x j from a list of keys (for example: j, k, l, m, q) to have a set of commands you can choose from by using only one key press. This would require implementation of an explicit  certain key which quits this behavior (preferably the q from the example list) instead of quitting by any key not in the list. Are you asking for a way making C-x added as preliminary to each typed key? But then you need a way to quit, "go out" of this behavior.

Comment: Is it maybe that you ask two questions in one? What about describing in detail the  expected behavior you ask finally for along with code of your failed attempt of achieving it? This would make it much easier to give an answer making it also possible to unambiguously determine if an answer answers the question.

Comment: @Claudio: See [phils](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/454)'s [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76610/76616#76616)

Comment: Yes, phils accepted answer addresses  the first part of your question and the other one addresses the means you need to create self-designed key sequences of any length triggering execution of any self-written elisp code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from Emacs 28.1:

```
** New mode 'repeat-mode' to allow shorter key sequences.
Type 'M-x repeat-mode' to enable this mode.  You can then type
'C-x u u' instead of 'C-x u C-x u' to undo many changes, 'C-x o o'
instead of 'C-x o C-x o' to switch windows, 'C-x { { } } ^ ^ v v' to
resize the selected window interactively, 'M-g n n p p' to navigate
next-error matches.  Any other key exits this temporarily enabled
transient mode that supports shorter keys, and then after exiting from
this mode, the last typed key uses the default key binding.

The user option 'repeat-exit-key' defines an additional key usable to
exit the mode like 'isearch-exit' ('RET').

The user option 'repeat-exit-timeout' (default nil, which means
forever) specifies the number of seconds of idle time after which to
break the repetition chain automatically.

When user option 'repeat-keep-prefix' is non-nil, the prefix arg of
the previous command is kept.  This can be used to e.g. reverse the
window navigation direction with 'C-x o M-- o o' or to set a new step
with 'C-x { C-5 { { {', which will set the window resizing step to 5
columns.

Command 'describe-repeat-maps' will display a buffer showing
which commands are repeatable in 'repeat-mode'.
```

Enable `repeat-mode` and then use <kbd>M-x</kbd>
`describe-repeat-maps` to see existing uses.

To create your own, add a `repeat-map` property to the symbol of the
command in question.  Here's an example from `bindings.el` which
implements this for the forward/back page commands which are bound to
<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>:

```el
(defvar page-navigation-repeat-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map "]" #'forward-page)
    (define-key map "[" #'backward-page)
    map)
  "Keymap to repeat page navigation key sequences.  Used in `repeat-mode'.")

(put 'forward-page 'repeat-map 'page-navigation-repeat-map)
(put 'backward-page 'repeat-map 'page-navigation-repeat-map)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you're saying that you want `C-c j` to be bound to a *repeatable* command, repeatable in the sense that you can just hold down a key (thus repeating it) to repeat the command.

There are several ways to do this -- you'll likely get several answers. I like this simple way. Define a function that defines a repeatable version of any command, then use that to define any number of repeatable commands.

```lisp
(defun repeat-command (command)
  "Repeat COMMAND."
  (require 'repeat)       ; Define its vars before we let-bind them.
  (let ((repeat-previous-repeated-command  command)
        (repeat-message-function           #'ignore)
        (last-repeatable-command           'repeat))
    (repeat nil)))
```

Then define a repeatable version of any existing command `some-command`, this way:

```lisp
(defun some-command+ ()
  "Repeatable version of command `some-command`.
You can repeat this by hitting the last key again..."
  (interactive)
  (require 'repeat)
  (repeat-command 'some-command))
```

If the original (nonrepeatable) `CMD` accepts an optional prefix arg, then just provide for that in the definition of the repeatable command, using `(interactive "P")`, etc.

This approach, by the way, works with any Emacs version, starting with Emacs 22 (which is when `repeat.el` was added to Emacs).

Comment: Is the purpose of this above to save one intermediate C-x z  key sequence which would do the same by repeating z?

Comment: @Claudio: The purpose is to be able to have a key, any key, including a key following a prefix key, any prefix key, repeat a command when you hold it pressed. E.g., `C-x y y y y y y ...`, yes, as opposed to, e.g., `C-x y C-x y C-x y C-x y C-x y C-x y C-x y`. (Becomes even more useful with a longer prefix key.)

Comment: I think [I didn't make my question very clear](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76610#comment126933_76610) (or maybe it is an XY question?). But your answer is also useful, +1, thanks :-)

Answer (score 4):

If it's custom code, you can use `set-transient-map` to temporarily set an overriding keymap for the next keystroke.

```
set-transient-map is a byte-compiled Lisp function in `subr.el'.

(set-transient-map MAP &optional KEEP-PRED ON-EXIT)

Set MAP as a temporary keymap taking precedence over other keymaps.
Normally, MAP is used only once, to look up the very next key.
However, if the optional argument KEEP-PRED is t, MAP stays
active if a key from MAP is used.  KEEP-PRED can also be a
function of no arguments: it is called from `pre-command-hook' and
if it returns non-nil, then MAP stays active.

Optional arg ON-EXIT, if non-nil, specifies a function that is
called, with no arguments, after MAP is deactivated.

This uses `overriding-terminal-local-map', which takes precedence over all
other keymaps.  As usual, if no match for a key is found in MAP, the normal
key lookup sequence then continues.

This returns an "exit function", which can be called with no argument
to deactivate this transient map, regardless of KEEP-PRED.
```